# Prove $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f_n ~dP_n = \int f ~dP$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence, solution-verification

Assume $f_n, ~n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $f$ are continuous functions where $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ and $P_n, ~n\in\mathbb{N}$ and are probability measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ where $P_n$ converges weakly to $P$.

**Edit:** $f$ is also bounded.

I want to prove that
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f_n ~dP_n = \int f ~dP.$$

**Solution:**

Uniform convergence of $f_n$ means
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 ~\exists n_1(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N} ~\forall n>n_1(\varepsilon): \Vert f_n - f \Vert_\infty < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
Weakly convegence of $P_n$ means
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 ~\exists n_2(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N} ~\forall n>n_2(\varepsilon): \vert \int g ~dP_n - \int g ~dP \vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
for any **bounded** continous function $g$.

Now I fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and $k:=\max\{n_1(\varepsilon),n_2(\varepsilon)\}$.

\begin{align}
\forall n > k:~~&\vert \int f_n ~dP_n - \int f ~dP\vert \\ 
&= \vert \int (f_n-f) ~dP_n + \int f ~dP_n -\int f ~dP\vert \\
&\leq \int \vert f_n-f \vert ~dP_n + \vert\int f ~dP_n -\int f ~dP\vert \\
&\leq \Vert f_n - f \Vert_\infty P_n(\mathbb{R}) + \vert \int f ~dP_n -\int f ~dP\vert \\
&\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon
\end{align}

Since, $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary the claim follows.

Comment: Maybe you can try to approximate with bounded functions or something like that.

Comment: What't the domain of your function $f_n$ and $f$?

Comment: Hm. Good question, the exercise doesn't specify it. Do you think a specific property which would help me?

Comment: Apparently this was an error in the specification of the exercise. So my solution should be fine.